# Using Django's annotate function while referencing another model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a three models: a User, Movie, and Rating model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

class Movie(models.Model):
    movie_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    imdb_rating = models.FloatField(null=True)
    rt_rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class Rating(models.Model):
    rating_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='ratings'
    )
    movie = models.ForeignKey(
        Movie,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='ratings'
    )
    rating = models.FloatField()
```

For Rating, I would like to annotate in a way where I have the difference of the `Rating.rating` and `Movie.imdb_rating`.

I also have `userRatings` which contains only the ratings by user with id = 1, to simplify things.

I tried using

```
userRating.annotate(imdb_diff=Value('rating') - Value('movie__imdb_rating'))
```

But I get the error

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field
```

How would I go about getting the correct annotation.

Comment: When I do that I get the error `TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): <django.db.models.fields.FloatField>.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse [`Value`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions) (used for literal values) and [`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) (used for database column names):

```
userRating.annotate(imdb_diff=F('rating')-F('movie__imdb_rating'))
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks a bunch.